# Incorrect shutdown of HDD

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown

I have 2 HDD on my laptop.
I installed the latest version of Ubuntu on hard drive No. 2
But I think I have a problem
When entering the Ubuntu system and turning off the device
The second hard drive is stopped incorrectly
It is as if the electrical power was cut off suddenly

Comment: You can check with the package `smartmontools`. Use its `smartctl --all` command to check the status of your drive(s).